# "sich behaben"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

The *Oxford English Dictionary* says the reflexive verb "behave oneself" is akin to what it calls the "modern" German verb "sich behaben". As far as I can tell, "sich benehmen" is a current locution and "sich behaben" is not. Is this a case of lexicographers considering something "modern" because it was used only five centuries ago? Or might it be more recent, e.g. two centuries?

Comment: According to Google's n-grams, "behaben", no matter what its meaning, was very, very rare in the 19th century. In the 20th and 21st centuries it's practically non-existent. I can confirm that I've never encountered that verb in decades of native speaking.

Comment: AFAIK, it is used - if at all - with a negative connotation, meaning someone behaved in a ponderous or hesitant manner.

Comment: It may be because I’m sleep-deprived but at present I’m failing to understand your question.

Comment: @Ingo: Did you mean "echauffieren"? I also was thinking of this, but can not really remember when I heard this.

Comment: Never heard or read of this: "sich behaben", IMHO it is not used at all and an error here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/behave

Comment: "Gehabt Euch wohl" habe ich mal gehört. Behabt?

Comment: Quoting from Thomas's link: "corresponding to modern German sich behaben".

Comment: Maybe we interpret the phrase "modern German" wrong? Maybe it's not meant to be "German spoken today", but any German not *Althochdeutsch* or *Mittelhochdeutsch*, so it could well be 18th century German, which is far from today's German?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : That was my surmise, but I wondered about specifics.

Comment: Btw, that online dictionary from Oxford is not the OED.

Comment: @CarstenS : That entry was copied from the OED. I first encountered it in the OED.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, good to know. I wished I still had access to that. Quite expensive...

Comment: probably "modern" in the epoch sense, not in the "currently used" sense.

Answer (score 3):

[dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/behaben) knows the verb *behaben* and defines it as follows:

> To act or behave in a certain way

The part "Etymologie" on that page may be interesting for you as well. Deduced from that is the adjective *behäbig*, which translates to:

> ponderous, sedate, stolid

Personally I've never heard *behaben* and even the Verb *gehaben* is rarely used today. The most common way it is used (even though crippled) is:

> Hab dich nicht so!
>   Don't make such a fuss!

Answer (score 2):

The only verb coming near to *behaben* is [gehaben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehaben) and the meaning would also match. Perhaps a typo?

In any case it would consider it dated in any meaning, not just in the *behave* counterpiece.

Comment: It does not match "behave oneself". "gehaben" is "demeanor to" by the way. "sich benehmen" fits better really.

Comment: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/displayLinkInfo.tcl?sigle=DWB&formid=GB02667

Comment: "diese alte bedeutung von behalten, behaupten dauert noch im 16 jh., doch verwechselte man behaben und beheben "

http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=behaben

Comment: @CarstenS: I have some difficulty with link-only comments. You proved, that such a word was known at some earlier time (Goethe used it with special meaning, Stieler from 1697 no longer lists it), but this surely does not qualify its use in a contemporary dictionary. So what is your statement exactly?

Comment: I understood the question as asking whether the claim of the word as *modern* should be understood as *Neuhochdeutsch* or would include *Frühneuhochdeutsch*. Therefore I do not think that it is helpful to claim that the word does not exist only because it is not currently in use.